# Foundation Export

Tags: ios, objective-c

What is the use of FOUNDATION EXPORT in Objective-c?

So I have:

KError.h

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *const KAPPErrorDomain;

enum {
    KPUnexpectedError = -1,
};
```

KError.m:

```
#import "KError.h"

NSString *const KAPPErrorDomain = @"com.kexample.myapp";
```

I assume that when you use Foundation_export in this case, it is to be able to use a variable in another file?

So that in KService.m, I cam reference KAppErrorDomain without any problem?

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Oops, did not see that ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. `FOUNDATION_EXPORT` is a macro that expands to `extern`
(or `extern "C"` in a C++ file), and that is the
keyword to declare a variable that is shared across source files (better: shared
across "translation units").

See [How do I use extern to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-share-a-variable-between-source-files-in-c-with-extern-but-how)
for many good answers why `extern` is necessary and how it works.